# Changing to Columns

Tags: r, excel

Suppose that I have a .txt file containing the following values (z_i is in a row under y_i, which is also in a row under the x_i):

```
x1
y1
z1


x2
y2
z2

x3
y3
z3

.
.
.

x1000
y1000
z1000
```

Now I would like to put all the xi's (for i in 1 ... 1000) in one column and all the yj's in one column and the same for zk's for j,k in 1...1000. This is because later I would like to calculate some values, say for example the standard error for all the x_i's and say the mean for all the y_j and so on. Please let me know how to convert my .txt file into an R or excel file containing three columns for the values of x_i, y_j and z_k

Many thanks

AB

Comment: I fixed the formatting which makes the question come over a bit more sensical. Is this what your text file looks like? (including 1 newline between first and second vales and two between second and third?)

Answer (score 3):

You can read the text file in R with

```
dat <- read.table("filename.txt")
```

This will create a data frame with one column.

Then you can create a matrix with three columns:

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(dat), 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

The output (the first three rows):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "x1" "y1" "z1"
[2,] "x2" "y2" "z2"
[3,] "x3" "y3" "z3"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried copying-and-pasting your data into excel?  Did that not work?

If you want to read it into R, use

```
myData <- read.csv(nameOfFileWithPath, sep=" ")
```

I am assuming from your example that your delimiter is `" "`.  If this is not the case, please modify that part accordingly.

If `read.csv` does not work, you can use `read.table` which allows more control.   Please refer to `?read.table` for more info.